# Why is there a phase difference between these Feynman diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, fermions

Here're some Feynman diagrams from my QFT notes:

[image]

I'm struggling with how to understand the minus signs on the right-hand side. For (1), is the minus sign arising from the antisymmetry of fermions? So if we exchange the label of the outgoing (or incoming) particles ($u$ and $t$ channel), there will be a minus sign on the Feynman amplitude and matrix element?

How about (2) and (3)? I'm not quite sure how I can explain the minus sign from these diagrams. Combine (1) and (2), is it right to say for fermion-fermion scatterings, the signs of matrix element for s, t, and u channels are always opposite?

Comment: So to be very brief all of these signs originate in the anticommutation relation of the fermions, so yes that works for (1) as you said, for (2) the reasoning is similar just arguing that essentially, connecting different fermions is in some sense "similar" to relabeling, for (3) I am not aware of an intuitive explanation, though a fermion loop always leads to a relative sign. Generally all these explanations just stem from explicitly calculating what integral these diagrams correspond to so that's probably your savest bet. (I think David Tong partially covers this in his QFT notes)

Comment: @Thomas Tappeiner Thanks for the comment! So combine (1) and (2), is it right to say for fermion-fermion scatterings, the signs of matrix element for s, t, and u channels are always opposite?

Comment: I'd have to double-check that that always works, but I think that should hold

Comment: @Thomas Tappeiner Thank you!!